# Sidekiq VS Thread.new to send email on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, email, asynchronous, sidekiq

I'm currently using `Sidekiq` as a solution to send email asynchronously on **Rails 4**.
But now that Rails is `Threadsafe by default`, is this a good solution to replace `Sidekiq` by a new Thread ? Is that solution safe or inappropriate ?

Thanks JD

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4 being thread-safe by default does *not* means that your code is auto-magically thread-safe, just that Rails itself (the framework) is thread-safe.

Therefore, I still think that it is a good idea to stick to Sidekiq, unless you are absolutely sure you can write a thread-safe implementation to handle asynchronous email sending on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing concepts here. "Rails is threadsafe" - this just means that rails puts a lock around code loading part, so that there's less chance for disaster (race conditions, etc). Your own code is not automatically made threadsafe.

Also, if you're on MRI (if you don't know which ruby you use, you're on MRI) - you can only run one thread at a time. So there's really no benefit in kicking off additional thread - it will synchronize with the others. These threads **won't be running in parallel** (which is your intention, I assume). Right now the only way to get parallel execution on MRI is multi-processing (running multiple processes). So that's where Sidekiq kicks in (*pun intended*) - it's an additional process that will run your jobs *in parallel*.

Don't use threads, use sidekiq.